# How to remove/disable Voice Talk on Ace 2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace-2

*Regular (not rooted) Samsung Galaxy Ace 2.*

How to disable or remove Voice Talk application? By disable I mean I don't want to see it ever again when I press double home button or anything like that.

Comment: Does your phone have an `S Voice` app?

Comment: I don't see it. I have Voice Talk (you double press home and it appears).

Comment: When the Voice Talk appears, is there any way you can go into its settings? See if this helps: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/58106/5342 Please feedback.

Comment: @geffchang, no change. I believe it is **additional** wake-up.