# changing the "hi galaxy" phrase. is it even possible?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-note, s-voice

Every once in a while, my note 3 wakes up on its own thinking somebody said "Hi Galaxy" and gets itself into the listening mode to start capturing what it hears from that moment on, then submits to Google for a search!

Boy! I had a few situations and eventually I had to turn off that awesome feature.

Is there a way to change this "hi galaxy" phrase to something less likely to be confused?
Can I personalize it?

Something like "ok Samsung, wake up now!" or "ok note 3, wake up now" etc...
the longer the phrase, the less likelyhood for an unintentional match, I assume.

Also, being able to personalize this phrase will prevent other people's getting your way... Imagine, the guy in the bus says "Hi galaxy" to his phone and all the galaxy devices in the bus within reach wakes up. LOL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `S Voice` app, and open its settings. You should be able to change it via `Set wake-up command`.

Here's the setting from my Samsung Galaxy S4:

[image]

Comment: no geffchang. that's a boolean setting. you'd think that would be the place to do so. but unfortunately, it is not.

Comment: @AverageJoe Uploaded the correct screenshot.

Comment: Wow! I can get there only when I take the path from "s find -> set wake-up command" route. Interestingly, for the note 3 I got (at&t), the setting you describe is not available; so "S Voice app -> open its settings" does not allow me to see "set wake-up command". but anyway, thanks to you, I used the s-find and get to that jem!

Comment: got it.:) Please see this link.  There, somebody else is also  making the same point that this setting is missing on note 3: http://support.t-mobile.com/thread/56280 also, even if I were to do the "sfind->set wake - up command", I'm unable to configure the function 2,3 and 4.  I wish there was a way to video capture the screen.

Comment: So, you were never able to change the command? I think you also misunderstood my previous comment. Although my answer helped you, it did not fix your problem. Instead, your solution fixed the problem. So I suggest adding your solution as an Answer (instead of it being just a comment), and accepting it later when you are able to (I think 2 days later). :)

Comment: Well, the fact of the matter is neither of our solutions fixed it. The problem is rooted in the note3 itself. Other samsung devices do not suffer from this. My method was a hack to get to the setting that you brought up (the `Set wake-up command` setting). In note 3, the only way you get there is by going thru the `s find-> wake`. But even that yields nothing because assigning various phrases are disabled on note3. In other words, your 2nd screenshot is available but disabled. It beats me as to why Samsung took this approach. I will keep your answer as still the one cause that's the closest.

Answer (score 0):

The "Set Wake-Up Command" you mentioned (via  S Find-> wake), is just a help file on the actual commands. If you go to the following, you can change what the Note 3 responds to on the lock screen:

Settings -> Device -> Lock Screen -> Wake up in lock screen -> Wake-up function X

(Note this is just the lock screen when the phone is set to swipe mode, not while it's asleep. Neither does this affect S Voice, but you can still do some cool things.)

Comment: my buck stops at settings>device>lock screen.

Comment: cause right there, I see, `Screen Security` & `Screen lock (none)` and nothing else. You sounded like I should have seen `Wake up in lock screen` option.

Answer (score 0):

The voice commands are part of the screen lock settings.  Touch the"screen lock" setting and it will take you to the"screen lock" settings which include "wake up commands". Once you check/turn on "wake up commands" you will have a new button below that should be called "set wakeup commands" or something similar.  I have a Galaxy S4.